# How to set SFMC FTP password to not expire?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ftp

I would like to set my Marketing Cloud Enhanced FTP password to not expire (or at least make the password not expire for longer than 3 months).

Is there documentation on this that I'm missing?

Comment: Is this for a salesforce.com technology? If so, which one? Please [edit] your question to include the relevant tags, otherwise this question may be flagged as being a [so] question instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about marketing cloud, you do this in setup:

[image]